# using -?> in Clojurescript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

In my Clojure shared source, I have the following (which I shamelessly stole):

```
(defmacro hey-str [name]
  `(str "hey " ~name))

{:author "Laurent Petit (and others)"
  :doc "Functions/macros variants of the ones that can be found in clojure.core 
            (note to other contrib members: feel free to add to this lib)"}

(defmacro- defnilsafe [docstring non-safe-name nil-safe-name]
  `(defmacro ~nil-safe-name ~docstring
     {:arglists '([~'x ~'form] [~'x ~'form ~'& ~'forms])}
       ([x# form#]
         `(let [~'i# ~x#] (when-not (nil? ~'i#) (~'~non-safe-name ~'i# ~form#))))
     ([x# form# & more#]
         `(~'~nil-safe-name (~'~nil-safe-name ~x# ~form#) ~@more#))))

(defnilsafe 
  "Same as clojure.core/-> but returns nil as soon as the threaded value is nil itself (thus short-circuiting any pending computation).
   Examples :
   (-?> \"foo\" .toUpperCase (.substring 1)) returns \"OO\"
   (-?> nil .toUpperCase (.substring 1)) returns nil
   "
  -> -?>)

(defnilsafe 
  "Same as clojure.core/.. but returns nil as soon as the threaded value is nil itself (thus short-circuiting any pending computation).
   Examples :
   (.?. \"foo\" .toUpperCase (.substring 1)) returns \"OO\"
   (.?. nil .toUpperCase (.substring 1)) returns nil
   "
   .. .?.)

(defnilsafe
  "Same as clojure.core/->> but returns nil as soon as the threaded value is nil itself (thus short-circuiting any pending computation).
   Examples :
   (-?>> (range 5) (map inc)) returns (1 2 3 4 5)
   (-?>> [] seq (map inc)) returns nil
   "
  ->> -?>>)
```

In my Clojurescript code I have the following (I :require-macros as c)

```
(def a nil)
(def b [])
(def c [{:a 23}])

(js/alert (c/hey-str "Stephen")) ;; should display "hey Stephen"
(js/alert (c/-?> a first :a)) ;; should display nil
(js/alert (c/-?> b first :a)) ;; should display nil
(js/alert (c/-?> c first :a)) ;; should display 23
```

Unfortunately, when I compile, I get:

```
WARNING: Use of undeclared Var webstack.client/-?> at line 56 cljs-src/webstack/client.cljs
WARNING: Use of undeclared Var webstack.client/-?> at line 57 cljs-src/webstack/client.cljs
WARNING: Use of undeclared Var webstack.client/-?> at line 58 cljs-src/webstack/client.cljs
```

When I open the javascript in a browser, I get the "hey Stephen" alert dialog, but the ubiquitous "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined" error comes up immediately after pressing "ok" on the "hey Stephen" alert. Sure enough, looking at the generated javascript code, my js/alert's became:

```
alert([cljs.core.str("hey "), cljs.core.str("Stephen")].join(""));
alert(webstack.client.__QMARK__GT_.call(null, webstack.client.__QMARK__GT_.call(null, webstack.client.a, cljs.core.first), "\ufdd0'a"));
alert(webstack.client.__QMARK__GT_.call(null, webstack.client.__QMARK__GT_.call(null, webstack.client.b, cljs.core.first), "\ufdd0'a"));
alert(webstack.client.__QMARK__GT_.call(null, webstack.client.__QMARK__GT_.call(null, webstack.client.c, cljs.core.first), "\ufdd0'a"))
```

So clearly, I can use macro's, but something about the way the -?> (and related) macros are written causes them to fail to compile. What do I need to do in order to use these `-?>` `.?.` and `-?>>' macros?

Comment: Rather than creating a macro (from the defnilsafe macro) for nil-safe-name can you try to make a function?

Comment: @Ankur no, it has to be a macro because it the expressions need to be arranged at compile/macroexpansion time prior to evaluation.

Comment: @rplevy: What I am saying that the macro is creating another macro, rather the macro can create a function

Comment: @Ankur How would you write `-?>` as a function?

Comment: @Cubic: Please see my answer for that

Comment: @Ankur that was a rhetorical question. The correct answer is, you can't.

Comment: Just a note from the future here, nowadays this is the `some->` macro, so it doesn't need to be reimplemented.

Answer (score 2):

-?> works for me using clojure 1.5.1 and cljsbuild 0.3.0, but only if I use :use-macros instead of :require-macros. When I use :require-macros clojurescript tries to resolve the macro as a var in the local namespace, which is incorrect. I think you've found a bug in clojurescript, why don't you report it?

```
(ns test.test
  ;(:use-macros [test.nilsafe :only [hey-str -?>]]) ;uncomment and everything works!
  (:require-macros [test.nilsafe :as tn]))

(def a nil)
(def b [])
(def c [{:a 23}])

(.log js/console (tn/hey-str "Stephen")) ;; should display "hey Stephen"
(.log js/console (tn/-?> a first :a)) ;; should display nil
(.log js/console (tn/-?> b first :a)) ;; should display nil
(.log js/console (tn/-?> c first :a))
```

The thing that makes me sure this is a bug is that uncommenting the :use-macros will cause the file to compile correctly, even if I don't remove the tn/ scope from the variables.

Answer (score 0):

The `->` marco is simple.

```
(defmacro ->
  "Threads the expr through the forms. Inserts x as the
  second item in the first form, making a list of it if it is not a
  list already. If there are more forms, inserts the first form as the
  second item in second form, etc."
  {:added "1.0"}
  [x & forms]
  (loop [x x, forms forms]
    (if forms
      (let [form (first forms)
            threaded (if (seq? form)
                       (with-meta `(~(first form) ~x ~@(next form)) (meta form))
                       (list form x))]
        (recur threaded (next forms)))
      x)))
```

write a nil safe one should be simple (example below is not tested), but you get the concept.

```
(defmacro -?>
  [x & forms]
  (loop [x x, forms forms]
    (if (and forms (some? x)) ; check nil to exit eariler
      (let [form (first forms)
            threaded (if (seq? form)
                       (with-meta `(~(first form) ~x ~@(next form)) (meta form))
                       (list form x))]
        (recur threaded (next forms)))
      x)))
```

Answer (score -1):

May be creating function rather than another macro from the macro can help you solve this issue:

```
(defmacro defnilsafe [docstring non-safe-name nil-safe-name]
  `(defn ~nil-safe-name ~docstring
     ([x# form#]
         (let [i# x#] (when-not (nil? i#) (~non-safe-name i# form#))))
     ([x# form# & more#]
         (apply ~nil-safe-name (~nil-safe-name x# form#) more#))))
```

Comment: Try `(-?> nil (println "hello world"))`. This doesn't do the same thing as the original macro. And how could it?

Comment: @Cubic, you are correct, it wont work with expressions as but will work with functions ex: `(-?> nil println)`

Comment: But this isn't what the -> macro does, and therefore isn't what the -?> macro should do.